# Yesod web app with Keter and Cloudflare's free SSL

Tags: haskell, ssl, cloudflare, yesod, keter

I have VPS running Debian 9 with Keter serving single web application.

I've generated certificates using `Create certificate` button in `Origin Certificates` section of `Crypto` tab.

Then I've edited my `keter.yaml`:

```
stanzas:
  - type: webapp

    exec: ../dist/bin/dummy-name
    args: []
    hosts:
      - dummy-domain.info


    ssl:
      key: /opt/keter/etc/cert/dummy-domain.info.key
      certificate: /opt/keter/etc/cert/dummy-domain.info.pem
```

There are also a remark:

```
    # Enable to force Keter to redirect to https
    # Can be added to any stanza
    # requires-secure: true
```

When I've uploaded new bundle it looks like that things does not work correct.  My website can be visited via HTTP (works as expected), and HTTPS, but it cannot load generated CSS and JS files from static (links injected in document have `http` scheme).

What else should I do to make everything work using secure HTTPS connection?

There are unclear options for keter:

```
  # for all stanzas
  requires-secure: true

  # stanza based
  host: ....
  secure: true
```

Also I have no idea which options should I use on CloudFlare too

```
SSL type now set to Flexible
Always Use HTTPS is OFF
```

Comment: Well, I suppose I have to edit my `keter-config.yaml` too, to make it listen port 443

Comment: Done, but still having same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally I've done following:

#### Application's `keter.yml`

```
stanzas:
  - type: webapp
    exec: ../dist/bin/dummy-name
    args: []
    hosts:
      - dummy-domain.info
    requires-secure: true
    ssl:
      key: /opt/keter/etc/cert/dummy-domain.info.key
      certificate: /opt/keter/etc/cert/dummy-domain.info.pem
```

#### Keter configuration on server `keter-config.yaml`

```
root: ..
#
# # Keter can listen on multiple ports for incoming connections. These ports can
# # have HTTPS either enabled or disabled.
listeners:
    # HTTP
        - host: "*4" # Listen on all IPv4 hosts
          port: 80 # Could be used to modify port
    # HTTPS
        - host: "*4"
          port: 443
          key: cert/dummy-domain.info.key
          certificate: cert/dummy-domain.info.pem
```

#### CloudFlare config:

**SSL** type now set to `Full`
**Always Use HTTPS** is `ON`

Also I've restarted keter service
`sudo service keter restart`

Now everything work as expected.